# Contact form will send the email, but when I reply, it get an error

Tags: php, html, css, forms, html-email

The Send button on my contact form, sends the email to *myaddress@myaddress.com*. But when I reply from the email address, I get an error and don't see where it may be.

The error is:

> Message not sent. Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
>   Server replied:
>   550 Your FROM address ( gmail.com , "Me"  ) must match
>   your authenticated email domain ( domainname.com ).

Treating this as a
spoofed email. I am at a lost for words. I have searched through the php file and contact form, and I don't have a gmail address anywhere. The php file code is as follows:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

            // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
            $email_to = "mail@domainname.com";

            $email_subject = "Message from website";


            function died($error) {
                // your error code can go here
                echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
                echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
                echo $error."<br /><br />";
                echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
                die();
            }

            // validation expected data exists
            if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
                !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
                !isset($_POST['email']) ||
                !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
                !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
                died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
            }

            $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
            $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
            $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
            $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
            $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

            $error_message = "";
            $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
          if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
            $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
          }
            $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
          if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
            $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
          }
          if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
            $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
          }
          if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
            $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
          }
          if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($error_message);
          }
            $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

            function clean_string($string) {
              $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
              return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
            }

            $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


        // create email headers
        $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
        ?>
```

This php file is saved as html_form_send.php. My form contact code is as follows:

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Is there any way someone could possibly tell me what's going on? Could it be something like the logs in the mail folder? I am lost...and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

what makes you think this is some thing to do with your code. If the Email gets sent correctly then surely the issue is with the email client your using to reply to the email address.

What are you using to reply to the email address?

Comment: I figured it was the server side. What I found out was the mail client has a redirect so I took it off and now it all works beautiful. Thanks!